# WPF MVVM - Correct way of OneWay data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to grasp the concept of MVVM using WPF, but I am still struggling. To show my problem, I made a very simple example where data binding does not work:

I have a UI with one Button and one TextBlock object. The TextBlock shows 0 at the beginning. Whenever the button is clicked, the value should increase by one.

This is my UI (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="CounterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:counter="clr-namespace:CounterTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <counter:CounterViewModel x:Key="counterviewobj"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,110,0,0" Text="{Binding CounterString, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource counterviewobj}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding IncCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource counterviewobj}}" Content="+1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I kept the code behind as clean as possible (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CounterTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

A Counter class is defined to do the business logic (Counter.cs).

```
namespace CounterTest
{
    public class Counter
    {
        public int Cval { get; set; } // This is the value to increment.

        public Counter() { Cval = 0; }

        public void Increment() { Cval++; }
        public bool CanIncrement() { return true; } // Only needed to conform to ICommand interface.
    }
}
```

I use a lightweight ICommand implementation (RelayCommand.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CounterTest
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action WhattoExecute;
        private Func<bool> WhentoExecute;
        public RelayCommand(Action What, Func<bool> When)
        {
            WhattoExecute = What;
            WhentoExecute = When;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return WhentoExecute();
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            WhattoExecute();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

And finally the ViewModel (CounterViewModel.cs):

```
namespace CounterTest
{
    public class CounterViewModel
    {
        private Counter myCounter = new Counter();
        private RelayCommand _IncCommand;
        public RelayCommand IncCommand
        {
            get { return _IncCommand; }
        }

        public string CounterString
        {
            get { return myCounter.Cval.ToString(); }
        }

        public CounterViewModel()
        {
            _IncCommand = new RelayCommand(myCounter.Increment, myCounter.CanIncrement);
        }
    }
}
```

Stepping through my code, I see that the command is executed when I press the button, and Cval is increased by one each time. But obviously I don't do the data binding correctly.

What did I try? I see two possible circumventions. The first is to bind the TextBlock directly to the Cval value of the Counter class. But this would violate all principles of MVVM.

The other one is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, bind the UpdateSourceTrigger to a PropertyChanged event from CounterString, and implement an update event for Cval which the setter from CounterString can subscribe to. But that is extremely cumbersome, and it also makes the OneWay binding in the XAML file moot.

There must be a better way. What do I miss? How can I update the TextBlock when Cval is changed and stick to the MVVM principles?

Comment: your view doesn't get notified when your CounterString changes. thus your binding doesn't update anything. you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your ViewModel and push the notification to your binding right after your Counter model changes

Comment: In MVVM you almost exclusively use Databinding via INotifyPropertyChanged. So much so, the language got syntax expansions to make it easier at v 5, 6 or so. And many MVVM frameworks somehow even manage to hide that code part away (do not ask me how). Really just look at the example for INotifyPropertyChanged. The Binding class will take care of the details.

Comment: @Mikant I tried to do this (see the edit), but it doesn't work. The binding doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Thern to make your updated(!) code work I replaced `private Counter myCounter = new Counter();` with `public Counter myCounter { get; set; } = new Counter();` - please notice the difference

Comment: and if you still really want to use your `CounterString` property for the binding please take a closer look at my first comment: you should call `RaisePropertyChanged("CounterString");` in your VM right after `RaisePropertyChanged("CVal");` in your M

Comment: @Mikant Wow, that really worked. And now I am confused that the rest of the code actually compiled, because since myCounter was private, the TextBlock Binding shouldn't even have known myCounter. Seems that debugging WPF is harder than I thought.

Comment: @Thern I had to make it public as just a proof of concept. you'd better take your previous version of code and follow the reccomendation I gave 2 mins ago

Comment: Mind to make this an answer so I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177238/discussion-between-mikant-and-thern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No command *knows* which binding should update is target right after it fires, thus it does nothing but invokes your method. To make WPF bindings work you should push some data change notifications to them. To change your code I'd highly recommend implemeting the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your **ViewModel**. Since your command is updating some property of your **Model**, the simpliest way for **ViewModel** to know the fact the **Model** is updated is to subscribe to the **Model** notification. Thus you'll have to implement that interface twice.
For simplicity I'll implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a some base class and inherit it in your **Model** & **ViewModel**:
INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CounterTest {
    public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) => OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace CounterTest {
    public class Counter : ModelBase {
        private int _cval;

        public int Cval { // This is the value to increment.
            get { return _cval; }
            set {
                if (_cval != value) {
                    _cval = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Cval));
                }
            }
        }

        public void Increment() { Cval++; }
        public bool CanIncrement() { return true; } // Only needed to conform to ICommand interface. // Mikant: not really needed. not here
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CounterTest {
    public class CounterViewModel : ModelBase {
        private readonly Counter _myCounter = new Counter();

        public RelayCommand IncCommand { get; }

        public CounterViewModel() {
            IncCommand = new RelayCommand(_myCounter.Increment, () => true);

            _myCounter.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void OnModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            switch (e.PropertyName) {
                case nameof(Counter.Cval):
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CounterString));
                    break;
            }
        }

        public string CounterString => $"Count is now {_myCounter.Cval}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was the missing link. So I in fact have to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of _myCounter. Then PropertyChanged of CounterString is called, which effectively calls the getter of the property and thus shows the value of _myCounter.Cval. Okay, this all makes sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your first idea sounds great!

Seriously, not every target of a binding has to be a first-level member on the view model. Its totally OK to go into an object (and you have to for collections!). If you go this route, you just need `Counter` to implement INPC. So you would just make your counter a public property then:

```
Text="{Binding CounterProp.CVal}"
```

If you still don't want to do that, then I would recommend making your command also raise property changed for the calculated property:

```
   _IncCommand = new RelayCommand(IncrementCounter, myCounter.CanIncrement
   ...

   private void IncrementCounter(object parameter)
   {
        myCounter.Increment(parameter);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CounterString)
   }
```

But really... the first one is easier to deal with, understand, and maintain. I don't see where it violates any principles of MVVM.

Comment: The issue with the first idea is that the View now is coupled to the Model, and wasn't the whole idea of MVVM to decouple View and Model?

Comment: @Them The idea is to decouple the view from, well, everything else. If it makes you sleep better you could always create a `CounterViewModel` that does more or less the same thing with a bunch of cumbersome work to sync the two, or a `CounterService` that acts on a data-only `Counter` but seriously, there is *no harm in binding like that*. The model is usually some backend, not the data objects that are used throughout the application anyways.

Comment: @Thern Debating the layers (almost always around DTOs for some reason) is almost always just a giant intellectual exercise that means absolutely nothing. Are there things that are obviously wrong? Sure. Is this one of them, heck no.

Comment: Okay, I changed the binding to {Binding myCounter.Cval}, but that also doesn't work, even though in debug mode it shows that the value is actually incremented. Sorry, I really don't have much idea of WPF and MVVM...

Comment: @Thern Is `Counter` raising PropertyChanged? Did you check for any binding errors?

Comment: I tried this with Counter class subscribing to INotifyPropertyChanged, raising the event when the setter of Cval is called, but it still doesn't change anything. See my edit of the question. One problem is that I don't know how to debug binding errors. It works, or it doesn't work. I don't know how to check where it goes wrong, and I fear this is all hidden in the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Thern Most binding errors can be found by looking for System.Data exceptions in your output log

Comment: Looking at the comments your issue is that the property you created wasn't public, you can only bind to public properties @Thern

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I somehow thought that this would give a compile time error (as it would when you try to access a private property from another class), but this obviously isn't the case.

Comment: Nope; binding errors pretty much never show up at compile time; just in the aforementioned exceptions